# Error en el efecto parallax imagen portada

Tags: html, css

he intentado hacer el efecto parallax en la imagen de mi portada pero no me sale, de tanto probar hice un caos de codigo y he tenido que volver desde el principio con la pagina web. deseo que al hacer scroll la foto de portada tenga el efecto parallax mientras el texto esta fijo. voy a poner el poco codigo que tengo hasta ahora pero creo que sería suficiente para hacerlo, muchas gracias de antemano

[![Así está actualmente, me gustaría que al hacer scroll la imagen tuviera el efecto parallax mientras el texto esta estático

```js
/**Menu Inicio*/
const toggle = document.querySelector(".toggle");
const menu = document.querySelector(".menu");
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

/* Toggle mobile menu */
function toggleMenu() {
  if (menu.classList.contains("active")) {
    menu.classList.remove("active");
    toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-bars'></i>";
  } else {
    menu.classList.add("active");
    toggle.querySelector("a").innerHTML = "<i class='fas fa-times'></i>";
  }
}

/* Activate Submenu */
function toggleItem() {
  if (this.classList.contains("submenu-active")) {
    this.classList.remove("submenu-active");
  } else if (menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
  } else {
    this.classList.add("submenu-active");
  }
}

/* Close Submenu From Anywhere */
function closeSubmenu(e) {
  if (menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
    let isClickInside = menu
      .querySelector(".submenu-active")
      .contains(e.target);

    if (!isClickInside && menu.querySelector(".submenu-active")) {
      menu.querySelector(".submenu-active").classList.remove("submenu-active");
    }
  }
}
/* Event Listeners */
toggle.addEventListener("click", toggleMenu, false);
for (let item of items) {
  if (item.querySelector(".submenu")) {
    item.addEventListener("click", toggleItem, false);
  }
  item.addEventListener("keypress", toggleItem, false);
}
document.addEventListener("click", closeSubmenu, false);
/**Menu Fin*/
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
}
.contenedor{
    max-width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
}
/*Menu*/
nav {
    background: #165279;
    padding: 6px 15px;
  }
  .menu a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .menu,
  .submenu {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .logo {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 7.5px 10px 7.5px 0;
  }
  .logo img{
    width: 70px;
  }
  .logobarco{
    width: 65px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    
  }
  .item {
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .item.button {
    padding: 9px 5px;
  }
  .item:not(.button) a:hover,
  .item a:hover::after {
    color: #ccc;
  }
  /* Mobile menu */
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .menu li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 7px 5px;
  }
  .menu li.subitem a {
    padding: 15px;
  }
  .toggle {
    order: 1;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .item.button {
    order: 2;
  }
  .item {
    order: 3;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
  }
  .active .item {
    display: block;
  }
  .button.secondary {
    /* divider between buttons and menu links */
    border-bottom: 1px #444 solid;
  }
  /* Submenu up from mobile screens */
  .submenu {
    display: none;
  }
  .submenu-active .submenu {
    display: block;
  }
  .has-submenu i {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  .has-submenu > a::after {
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    font-weight: 900;
    content: "\f078";
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }
  .subitem a {
    padding: 10px 15px;
  }
  .submenu-active {
    background-color: #111;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
  
  /* Tablet menu */
  @media all and (min-width: 700px) {
    .menu {
      justify-content: space-between;

    }
    .logo {
      flex: 1;
    }
    .item.button {
      width: auto;
      order: 1;
      display: block;
    }
    .toggle {
      flex: 1;
      text-align: right;
      order: 2;
    }
    /* Button up from tablet screen */
    .menu li.button a {
      padding: 10px 15px;
      margin: 5px 0;
    }
    .button a {
      background: #0080ff;
      border: 1px royalblue solid;
    }
    .button.secondary {
      border: 0;
    }
    .button.secondary a {
      background: transparent;
      border: 1px #0080ff solid;
    }
    .button a:hover {
      text-decoration: none;
    }
    .button:not(.secondary) a:hover {
      background: royalblue;
      border-color: darkblue;
    }
  }
  /* Desktop menu */
  @media all and (min-width: 960px) {
    .menu {
      align-items: flex-end;
      flex-wrap: nowrap;
      background: none;
    }
    .logo {
      order: 0;
    }
    .item {
      order: 1;
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: auto;
    }
    .button {
      order: 2;
    }
    .submenu-active .submenu {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 68px;
      background: #111;
    }
    .toggle {
      display: none;
    }
    .submenu-active {
      border-radius: 0;
    }
  }

  /*Redes*/

  .redes{
  
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 8px 0;

  }
  .red{
    display: flex;
    gap: 5rem;
  }
  .red img{
    width: 21px;
  }

/*Banner*/
.banner{
    position: relative;
    widows: 100%;
    height: calc(108vh - 500px);
    background-image: url(img/image00007.jpeg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
.capa{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.contenido{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
.contenido h1{
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.contenido p{
    margin: 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.contenido .button{
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 9px 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    width: 150px;
}
.contenido .button:hover{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
}

/*Banner*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Mallorca Mar Excursiones - Alquiler de embarcaciones</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lightbox.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="redes">
            <div class="red">
                <a href="#"><img src="img/001-tik-tok.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/002-whatsapp.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/003-instagram.png" alt=""></a>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/004-facebook.png" alt=""></a>

            </div>
        </div>

        <nav>
            <div class="contenedor">
                <ul class="menu">

                    <a href="index.html">
                        <li class="logo"><img src="img/MallorcaMar_BN_FondoTransparente.png" alt="">
                        </li>
                    </a>

                    <li class="item"><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="galeria.html">Galería</a></li>
                    <li class="item"><a href="reserva.html">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li class="item has-submenu">

                        <a tabindex="0">Excursiones</a>
                        <ul class="submenu">
                            <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Bahía de Palma</a></li>
                            <li class="subitem"><a href="#">Pasifico</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li class="toggle"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </nav>

        <div class="banner">
            <div class="capa">
                <div class="contenido">
                    <h1>Mallorca Mar Excursiones</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ducimus, eum facilis eos magnam
                        praesentium ipsa tenetur debitis sequi corporis animi sunt nulla libero similique. Illo
                        laboriosam error veniam perferendis sapiente blanditiis deserunt. Laboriosam nulla sapiente
                        distinctio facilis obcaecati nesciunt mollitia eum id pariatur hic sed recusandae, incidunt
                        dolorem ullam atque.</p>
                    <center><a href="#" class="button">Reservar</a></center>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="contenedor">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Pariatur maiores excepturi sed, quia harum perspiciatis, placeat adipisci non, nihil cumque cum magnam consectetur! Omnis hic ab iure minus, delectus eius itaque asperiores accusantium, corporis laborum non nemo, eos corrupti exercitationem. Excepturi autem delectus mollitia, similique veniam praesentium odio ex natus cumque illum, dolore totam? Laudantium ex, sunt dolore animi cum eos illo aliquid laboriosam nemo quaerat quae. Iste sit suscipit neque soluta hic atque eaque voluptatibus voluptate dolor itaque aspernatur, non natus excepturi, in dolore, fugit eveniet inventore cumque. Quasi, sapiente qui quam repellendus, debitis ea praesentium saepe rerum autem quas, nam maxime sit repellat eum sequi itaque assumenda deleniti explicabo esse nisi modi aliquam! Iure eligendi enim adipisci non voluptas culpa error, rem sed rerum a dolorum amet odit temporibus dolorem ratione quisquam quam esse doloribus deserunt obcaecati! Incidunt natus delectus iusto odit. Similique, velit odit sit sed enim maiores aspernatur laboriosam sunt, illo nisi iste excepturi inventore quam placeat animi saepe. Est, culpa corporis enim amet ea quos, reprehenderit maxime velit autem incidunt sapiente quisquam alias magni? Aperiam obcaecati, ipsum repudiandae consequatur quia odio alias saepe animi. Quidem amet consequatur, fuga sequi illo praesentium! Recusandae sapiente deleniti ipsam delectus harum deserunt fugit obcaecati, minus debitis corrupti tenetur suscipit laborum officiis et consequatur commodi quo sint, eligendi beatae, voluptate at dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam suscipit repellat sint veritatis similique saepe consequuntur tempore consectetur placeat. Aut libero, quo ea optio aliquam hic nemo, quas, laboriosam ad neque commodi vo dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam  dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam suscipit repellat sint  dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam suscipit repellat sint suscipit repellat sint luptas ipsam eveniet doloremque explicabo labore magni nostrum  dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam suscipit repellat sint  dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam suscipit repellat sint reiciendis? Sit, totam sapiente, mollitia veniam nam aperiam debitis possficiis et consequatur commodi quo sint, eligendi beatae, volup dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam suscipit repellat sint tate at dolore voluptas placeat! Asperiores provident illo quasi, nulla reiciendis, placeat a esse natus ipsam quaerat earum facere cum delectus suscipit sit quia, eius cupiditate. Omnis ullam suscipit repellat sint veritatis similique saepe consequuntur tempore consectetur placeat. Aut libero, quo ea optio aliquam hic nemo, quas, laboriosam ad neque commodi imus omnis molestiae, cumque similique dolorem! Quia consequatur quae quasi nulla autem voluptas nesciunt temporibus mollitia la Accusamus quo nemo unde aliquam voluptas laboriosam quaerat? Eveniet consequuntur officia aperiam asperiores iusto?</p>
        </div>
    </main>





    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuO68.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuO68.png)